# Authentication with PHP 8.0-Password protecting files and folders with .htaccess and .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I'm trying to password protect certain folders and files in my Apache directory. I place the .htaccess file in the folder and when I go to that directory, the browser asks for Authentication.

I tried creating a password from the command-line with the command, htpasswd -c .htpasswd client.
The client username already exists in my .htpasswd file, but it doesn't prompt me to generate a new password.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AuthUserFile C:/Apache24/htdocs/PHPandMySQL-2020/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Folder"
Require valid-user
```

and my .htpasswd looks like this:

```
client: f.i9PC3.AtcXE
```

The authentication works on the folder. But when I go to the command-line, and type: htpasswd -c .htpasswd client. It doesn't prompt me to generate a new password.

Can anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: What is the response from typing that command?

Comment: It says it doesn't recognize the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says it doesn't recognize the command.

It doesn't prompt for the password because you're not actually running the command! The `htpasswd.exe` executable is normally installed in the `bin` subdirectory of the Apache installation. So, if it's located at `C:\Apache24\bin\htpasswd.exe` then you need to use the following at the command prompt in the appropriate directory.

```
> C:\Apache24\bin\htpasswd -c .htpasswd client
```

Or, navigate to the `bin` directory and pass the full path to the `.htpasswd` file on the command line.

Or, [add the `bin` directory to the Windows `PATH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows) to avoid having to type the full file-path to the command.

Comment: Creating a password seems to work now. The only problem is that when I do create a new password it doesn't update the .htpasswd file. My path is: C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/access/.htpasswd  Is this path wrong? The folder access is on my Desktop and the file .htpasswd is in the folder.